# No errors or results when executing simple query on SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ms-access

This is my first approach to SQL Server. I have exported my Access DB to SQL Server and want to use it in my application. I have added the new SQL DB to my C# project and replaced `OleDB` with `Sql`. I am now unable to execute queries which where perfectly working with local DB in Access.

Query:

```
string query = @"SELECT SessionID, SemesterA, SemesterB, RoomID, SessionDate, SessionTimeStart, SessionTimeEnd" +
               " FROM [Session] " +
               " WHERE RoomID = @RoomID " +
               " AND SessionDate = getdate() ";
```

I have replaced `Date()` with `getdate()` as instructed by the VS error, but the query does not produce any result (should return one record, Access DB does)

My RoomSelect form code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AutoReg
{
    public partial class RoomSelect : Form
    {

        DataTable queryResult = new DataTable();
        public string RoomID;
        RoomActiveSession RoomActiveSessionForm = new RoomActiveSession();

        public RoomSelect()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            switch (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                case "MB0302":
                    RoomID = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    roomQuery();
                    break;

                case "MC1001":
                    RoomID = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    roomQuery();
                    break;

                case "MC3203":
                    RoomID = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
                    roomQuery();
                    break;

                case "MC3204":
                    RoomID = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    roomQuery();
                    break;

            }
        }

        public void roomQuery()
        {
            string ConnStr = "Data Source=DUZY;Initial Catalog=AutoRegSQL;Integrated Security=True";

            SqlConnection MyConn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr);
            MyConn.Open();

            //SQL query that todays sessions for the given roomID
            string query = @"SELECT SessionID, SemesterA, SemesterB, RoomID, SessionDate, SessionTimeStart, SessionTimeEnd" +
               " FROM [Session] " +
               " WHERE RoomID = @RoomID " +
               " AND SessionDate = getdate() ";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, MyConn);

            command.Parameters.Add("RoomID", SqlDbType.Char).Value = RoomID;


            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

            adapter.Fill(queryResult);

            if (queryResult.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No active sessions today for the given room number");
                MyConn.Close();
            }
            else
            {

                RoomActiveSessionForm.SetDataSouce(queryResult);

                this.Hide();
                RoomActiveSessionForm.ShowDialog();

                MyConn.Close();
            }


        }

    }
}
```

When I run the program, I receive a message "No active sessions today for the given room number" which should be executed when there are no results to the query, but I know for a fact, that it should return one record)

Comment: No query results, I'm expecting one record to be returned.

Comment: if you execute your query against database do you get one record?

Comment: What is the expected value of SessionDate and what are you trying to pass in. `GetDate()` returns the time of the moment you ran your query, is that what you where wanting to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `getdate()` actually returns a `datetime`.  Try converting it to a date:

```
AND SessionDate = cast(getdate() as date)
```

The time component is probably the problem -- preventing a match between the date and the datetime.

Comment: +1 but this assumes the data stored doesn't have a time component - might need a convert on both sides or, better yet, a range query.

Comment: AND SessionDate = cast(getdate() as date) - this line now prevents the message box from showing and the query continues by going to another form (this is the form where I display my results), but still no records shown

Comment: @jaspernorth in that case you need to put in a breakpoint, and step though with a debugger and find out what is not happening correctly as that is a different issue of you not displaying the results, mostlikely a issue with `RoomActiveSessionForm.SetDataSouce`

Comment: It was my mistake to not refresh DGV in other form to display data. Your answer was very helpfull. Thanks @GordonLinoff

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . The `Date()` function in Access returns the date without a time.  The OP says that replacing that with `getdate()` caused the code to stop returning results.

Comment: Well, it seemed unlikely to me that `SessionDate` did not contain time, since that is pretty rare, but hey, if that worked in this case, great. Still think it's worth mentioning since in a lot of cases it won't.